# Socket IO . How to change url path

Tags: url, socket.io

How to change url path of socket.io.js

my socket.io.js is located at

> https://192.168.236.100/socket.io/socket.io.js

what if i want to change it like:

> https://192.168.236.100/socket.conference/socket.io.js

thank you

Comment: Just make a route for `/socket.conference/socket.io.js` and serve the appropriate client script file from inside the node_modules directory from that route handler.

Comment: FYI, here's the code that socket.io uses to serve it from `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.  https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/c7de1a1adf4dcb81e974c6d74989400ebd535ba0/lib/index.js#L249.

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00 where can i change the variable `this._path` ?

Comment: this one https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/c7de1a1adf4dcb81e974c6d74989400ebd535ba0/lib/index.js#L45 ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not as simple as changing the `this._path` value or passing in the path option to the constructor because if you change that, it also affects how a socket.io client must connect to the server too, not only how the socket.io.js file is served.

The simplest way I could find to make the `socket.io.js` file appear to be coming from a different path and not change anything else is to just create a new route for it like this:

```
app.get("/socket.conference/socket.io.js", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"));
});
```

This assumes that socket.io is installed locally in the directory that your `app` file is running from.  If it is installed somewhere differently, then you need to find where the `/socket.io-client/socket.io.js` path/file is and use the right path to that.

This works with this client `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="/socket.conference/socket.io.js"></script>
```